# Combining different types of Animations

Tags: geometry-nodes, smoke-simulation

I am new to blender and I am currently working on a project where I animated the firing of laser using geometry nodes. After the laser strikes the particular target I want to have smoke released in a controlled direction. Also is there any way where I can carve out shapes out of a single block like a tube or a cylinder through which the smoke can go.

Comment: Hello, @Siddarth.. welcome..  interesting question, but a bit vague. There are too many possible approaches. An illustration of the exact effect you seek, in particular what you _mean_ by 'controlled direction' would make it easier for us to avoid giving the right answer to the wrong question. Please edit to specify more closely.